# Javascript image map, change div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

Okay i have 5 image maps,

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area id="Frame1" shape="poly" coords="549,225,687,234,682,373,543,366" href="#" alt="Frame 1" />
    <area id="Frame2" shape="poly" coords="702,219,705,354,841,347,833,213" href="#" alt="Frame 2" />
    <area id"Frame3" shape="poly" coords="482,376,476,510,624,515,627,383" href="#" alt="Frame 3" />
    <area id"Frame4" shape="poly" coords="653,540,646,404,748,403,755,537" href="#" alt="Frame 4" />
    <area id"Frame5" shape="poly" coords="764,513,882,515,885,370,764,368" href="#" alt="Frame 5" />
</map>
```

and some separate divs

```
<div id="person-1-slide-1"><img src ="images/allnewpictures/3.png" /></div>
<div id="person-2-slide-1"><img src = "images/allnewpictures/2.png" /></div>
<div id="person-3-slide-1"><img src ="images/allnewpictures/1.png"/></div>
```

trying to make it when i hover over one of the image map areas, the div will change so hovering over image map 1, changes  div "person-1-slide-1" to display the img in div `id"person-2-slide-1"`

What im asking is there javascript for mouseover image map, change div so the picture changes.

Comment: Your html contains errors. Be sure you fix them before attempting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to each area specifying which div should be changed:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map"> 
      <area id="Frame1" data-ref="person-1-slide-1" shape="poly" coords="549,225,687,234,682,373,543,366" href="#" alt="Frame 1" />
      <area id="Frame2" data-ref="person-2-slide-1" shape="poly" coords="702,219,705,354,841,347,833,213" href="#" alt="Frame 2" />
      <area id"Frame3" data-ref="person-3-slide-1" shape="poly" coords="482,376,476,510,624,515,627,383" href="#" alt="Frame 3" />
      <area id"Frame4" data-ref="person-4-slide-1" shape="poly" coords="653,540,646,404,748,403,755,537" href="#" alt="Frame 4" />
      <area id"Frame5" data-ref="person-5-slide-1" shape="poly" coords="764,513,882,515,885,370,764,368" href="#" alt="Frame 5" />
</map>
```

Then try this:

```
$('map area').hover(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).data('ref')).find('img').show();
},
function() {
    $('#'+$(this).data('ref')).find('img').hide();
});
```